# Select drop down value using selenium RC

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

There is a drop down with 2 values enabled and disabled, but the field has type=button.
I am not sure how to select values in this drop down.

Below is the html code for the element

```
<button id="loggingTargetStatus" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents dijitDownArrowButton" waistate="haspopup-true,labelledby-loggingTargetStatus_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="focusNode,titleNode,_arrowWrapperNode" value="" type="button" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="loggingTargetStatus_label" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline cpmIconStateEnable" dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></span>
<span id="loggingTargetStatus_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" dojoattachpoint="containerNode,_popupStateNode">Enabled</span>
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonInner"> </span>
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonChar">▼</span>
</button>
```

Please suggest how to select using selenium RC

Comment: [tag:selenium-rc] has been deprecated for several YEARS now. Are you unable to upgrade to [tag:selenium-webdriver]? You do know that [tag:selenium2] supports both APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `select` element, and so you cannot interact with it as such. It probably uses AJAX to make it *look* like a select menu.

You will need to `click()` on all the appropriate elements. It has been years since I have used [selenium-rc](/questions/tagged/selenium-rc), so the below code will probably need to be adjusted.

```
selenium.click("loggingTargetStatus");    // to enable the menu
selenium.click(your_field);    // you will have to find the correct locator
```